# Browser popup blocker blocking jasper reports generated from flex

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, popup, timer, jasper-reports

I have a flex application that uses navigateToURL() to call a servlet. The servlet in turn generates a JasperReport and then uses exportReport() to show the report in a new browser tab.

Now, my problem is this. I want to generate multiple reports at once, each opening in its own tab. It all works fine except that in Firefox the built in browser pop-up blocker sees every new tab that is opened after the first report tab as a pop-up. It blocks this and is giving me endless headaches.

I also tried this in IE8, Safari, Chrome and Opera with no problems.

Any help as to how I can get past the Firefox pop-up blocker would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I use a timer in the loop that I use to fire calls to the servlet. Reason for this is that without the delay from the timer the servlet gets hit too fast for the reports to generate. Could it be that the browser sees the timer as malicious and therefor blocks all popups after the first one?